# While loop escape range

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have a while loop i wish to escape when i hit the number 1 through 5.

What would be the best statement to put for that?

I currently have this.

```
while (  oneChoice!= 1 ||  oneChoice!= 2 || oneChoice!= 3 || oneChoice!= 4 || oneChoice!= 5  )
{
cout << "Please make a selection" << endl;
cout << "Choose once more: ";
cin >> oneChoice;
break;
}
```

Comment: Its being used within another while loop within a switch statement

Comment: `break` breaks out of the *innermost* loop or switch; in this context, it makes the code inside the loop execute no more than once, regardless of the value of `oneChoice`.  In other words, given what you've said this is supposed to do, it shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `oneChoice` is an `int` (and thus can't have a value between 1 and 2, for example), just change the conditional to:

```
while (!(1 <= oneChoice && oneChoice <= 5))
```

or, equivalently:

```
while (oneChoice < 1 || oneChoice > 5)
```

Additionally, if `oneChoice` has no real meaning or importance before entering the loop, it would probably be better practice to use a `do { ... } while (oneChoice < 1 || oneChoice > 5);` loop instead.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it like this:

```
int n;
for (;;)
{
    cout << "Please make a selection (1-5): "
    cin >> n;
    if (n >= 1 && n <= 5) break;
    cout << "You must choose a number from 1 through 5.\n";
}
```

The break goes in the middle so that the error message is printed only if the user enters a value outside the acceptable range.  `for (;;)` is proper C-family idiom for a loop where you don't want to have an exit condition tested at the top or bottom.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (oneChoice < 1 or oneChoice > 5)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: That means as long as anything is not within that range it is false correct? Meaning anything inside the range is true meaning it will leave?

Comment: Yes. And do not use that `break` in the loop.

Comment: I had to use break for something im doing.

Comment: What is that `or` doing there?  It should be `||`.

Comment: Oh, right, the alternative tokens.  Those only exist for the sake of systems dependent on ISO646 national variants (to first order, no such systems exist anymore) and should never be used except in C++ compliance tests.